# WP7 Playing a sound - getting notified when a sound is done playing

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I am playing a sound like this:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream stream;

stream = isoStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open);
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effect.Play();
```

Is there a way to get notified when playing has finished? I would need this to disable the play button while playing and then enable it back again when finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `effect.Duration` [propetry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect_members.aspx) to set  `button.Enable` play button by timer.